# Alamofire Add Path Variable to Url

Tags: swift, alamofire, url-parameters

How can i use that kind GET request "http://someApi/someEndPoint/:variable1/:variable2" in alamofire.
That variables contents some strings, like variable1 = "USD" and variable2 = "weekly"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna get, for instance, blah1:

```
static var APIendPoint = "http://someApi.blah.blah"

static var blah1: String {
     return APIendPoint + "/blah1"
}
```

which gives you access to `"http://someApi.blah.blah/blah1"`

and if you have a path paramter like this: `"http://someApi.blah.blah/blah1{blahID}/blah2`

you would do similar approach like in this way:

```
static func getBlah2(blahID: String) -> String {
        return blah1 + "/\(blahID)" + "/blah2"
    }
```

and just call this in your API request, easier using alamofire:

```
func api(id: Int = 0) {
AF. request(YourAPI.getBlah2(blahID: id), method .get) .. . 
.. . 
}
```

easier.. .

Answer (score 2):

There is not build-in support for this in `Alamofire`. You can take the plain string interpolation approach like this:

```
let urlString = "http://someApi/someEndPoint/\(variable1)/\(variable2)"
```

Comment: Just no. This is not about parsing local variable. There is a methot to create get api like "/:variable". "Variable" literally take place into url

Comment: @cagatayegilmez  Are you looking for a different final result from this?

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire doesn't support any sort of automatic path parameter encoding. Instead, you can build your paths programmatically using string interpolation.

```swift
var url = URL(string: "http://someApi/someEndPoint/")!
url.appendPathComponent("\(variable1)")
url.appendPathComponent("\(variable2)")
```

Comment: Hi Jon, i tried that way but this appends querry parameter to url. I'm looking for path variable

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `appendingPathComponent` appends to the path, so you'd end up with `http://someApi/someEndPoint/variable1/variable2`.